# Compatibility Level of SQL Server Backups

Tags: sql-server

I'm running MSSQL 2014. I'm currently working on a database with a compatibility level of 2008. I recently backed up my working copy and sent it off to one of my .NET subs to work on an application extension. He claims his BAK file has a compatibility level of 2014. I'm skeptical. If he's right, is there a way I can configure the backup to retain the compatibility level of the database and not adopt the compatibility level of my server?

Answer (score 1):

These are two different things. Backup file can be restored only on the same SQL server version and (usually) two following versions. You can't use backup file at older instances.

[Database compatibility level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) limits functionalities you can use within database like data types, build in functions etc.

Comment: Jan, Thanks for the great feedback. It get it. I was mistakenly comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to generate database script with schema and data.that's it and it will work for most of your sql server. and if you found any error during execution of script you can clearly get idea reason for that , like such function or key word not compatible with sql etc.

Comment: Or, easier yet, I'll tell my sub to upgrade his MSSQL server. :) Thanks Kaushik.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of SQL sever errors on restore can also be caused by a difference in the backup schema.

Verify the database on the source system with something like the following

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK ='P:\Backup\<fileName>P'
```

Then do the same on the target restore system.

Have a look at the SQL Server Version on each system with the following.

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

Read this document about the changes in the backup schema.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5014298-fix-error-3241-occurs-during-executing-restore-database-or-restore-log-8b6649d4-5de0-4105-96ac-85d4eaa4d00a

And consider restoring backups to the target system without compression until the target system can be upgrade to the same CU version.